# In python, is 'foo == (8 or 9)' or 'foo == 8 or foo == 9' more correct?

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement, boolean

When programming in python, when you are checking if a statement is true, would it be more correct to use `foo == (8 or 9)` or `foo == 8 or foo == 9`? Is it just a matter of what the programmer chooses to do? I am wondering about python 2.7, in case it is different in python 3.

Comment: Both are not equivalent... `foo == (8 or 9)` isn't what you probably think it is.

Comment: clearly, you don't understand how "or" operator works.  Any non-zero integer is logically TRUE. then...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You probably want `foo == 8 or foo == 9`, since:

```
In [411]: foo = 9

In [412]: foo == (8 or 9)
Out[412]: False

In [413]: foo == 8 or foo == 9
Out[413]: True
```

After all, `(8 or 9)` is equal to `8`:

```
In [414]: (8 or 9)
Out[414]: 8
```

Alternatively, you could also write

```
foo in (8, 9)
```

This holds for Python3 as well as Python2.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`foo == (8 or 9)` is not the same as `foo == 8 or foo == 9`and the latter is the correct form.

`(8 or 9)` evaluates to `8` since in Python `or` evaluates to the first operand (left to right) that is 'truthy', or `False` if neither is, so the check becomes a plain `foo == 8`.